# checking an object's attribure and a variable for equality

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the below code. I want to enter a color and message in input in format : "Input: blue, 'message'" and it should print the size of blue ball i.e. 4. But this method is not working.

```
class Ball(object):

    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.color = color
        self.size = size

    b = []
    b.append(Ball('red', '3'))
    b.append(Ball('blue', '4'))
    b.append(Ball('green', '5'))
    b.append(Ball('grey', '6'))
    b.append(Ball('black', '7'))
    b.append(Ball('purple', '8'))

    inp = input()
    temp_inp = inp.split(':')[1]
    inp_, message = [x.lower() for x in temp_inp.split(",")]
    for each in b:
        if inp_ == each.color:
            print(each.size)
```

If i try the same equality operator with input it works fine.
    class Ball(object):

```
    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.color = color
        self.size = size

    b = []
    b.append(Ball('red', '3'))
    b.append(Ball('blue', '4'))
    b.append(Ball('green', '5'))
    b.append(Ball('grey', '6'))
    b.append(Ball('black', '7'))
    b.append(Ball('purple', '8'))

    inp = input()
    for each in b:
    if inp == each.color:
        print(each.size)
```

Comment: Is the indentation non your example correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have an extra space in your string `inp_`. You don't notice it while printing but you need to strip it before you compare.

```
inp = "Input: blue, 'message'"
temp_inp = inp.split(':')[1]
inp_, message = [x.lower().strip() for x in temp_inp.split(",")] # <--- strip here

for each in b:
    if inp_ == each.color:
        print(each.size)

# 4
```

Comment: I don't know how i missed such a small detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your input message is of the form `blah: colour, message`. First your split on ":", and take the second element, which gives you " colour, message". When you later split on "," you get " colour" and " message". Note the leading spaces! So when you compare with our Ball instances you're comparing, for example "blue" and " blue", which won't match because not the space.

You can get around this by either using the `strip` method to remove spaces at the end or beginning of your strings. Either that or change your input.